# K2 Advice and other products

Tags: k2, nintex-workflow

This probably sounds like a pretty stupid question but I'm at a bit of a loss and getting even more confused with the more I read on google...so if anyone could provide any advice that would be great.

Do you need to have K2 Blackpearl to have K2 SmartForms? or can you buy one without the other?

Also would anyone have any suggestions on software that is similar to Nintex or K2 SmartForms?

Many Thanks for any help/ advice you's can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a stupid question at all. You do need K2 Blackpearl to have Smartforms. Blackpearl is the engine and Smartforms an add-on. More information on the link below.

https://help.k2.com/onlinetraining/bp1/default.htm#100ABZ/The-K2-Platform.htm%3FTocPath%3D100ABZ%253A%2520Introduction%2520to%2520K2%7CPart%25201%253A%2520K2%2520in%2520the%2520enterprise%7C_____4